# Syncing Associations

Tags: php, laravel

I have some relations:

```
public function handleServices(array $services): bool
    {
        $allServicesId = $this->services()->get(['service_id'])->pluck('service_id')->toArray();
        return ManyToManyHelper::manageRelations($this->services(), $allServicesId, $services);
    }
```

There I use `ManyToManyHelper`

```
class ManyToManyHelper
{
    public static function manageRelations(BelongsToMany $relation, array $allIds, array $manageIds): bool
    {
        try {
            foreach ($manageIds as $categoryId) {
                if (!in_array($categoryId, $allIds)) {
                    $relation->attach($categoryId);
                }
            }

            $toDeleteIds = array_diff($allIds, $manageIds);
            if (count($toDeleteIds) > 0) {
                $relation->detach($toDeleteIds);
            }
            return true;

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But I try to use `Syncing Associations` - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

And I don't understand at all how to change `Many to Many` to `sync`.

Can I get any example?

I have one example (https://www.scratchcode.io/source-books/laravel-sync-with-an-example/) but It doesn't give me success

Comment: It's not clear what you need to do here. For example `$relation->sync($manageIds)` will ensure `$relation` is related to all ids in `$manageIds` and **only** those ids i.e. will add the relationships that are missing and remove the ones that are already there but not listed in `$manageIds`

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, that's why I need to use ```sync```.
The idea of the ```helper``` is to just find the difference between foreign keys and the current records bound to the model and attach some, unhook some - in fact, the ```sync``` function does this.

Comment: Something like just using `$this->services()->sync($services)`?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, I mean it (or some like it). Check my answers below please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
public function handleServices(array $services): bool {
    $this->services()->sync($services); 
    return true;
}
```

This will ensure that all ids listed in `$services` and only those ids are associated with `$this` model's `services` relationship. This is assuming that `$this` is a model and `$services` has the list of ids that you want to strictly associate.

Comment: As I understand It is that I need. I try your code, but no one changes does not appear, I mean that I have not any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question isn't clear, what about this?

```
         foreach ($manageIds as $categoryId) {
            $toDeleteIds = array_diff($allIds, $manageIds);
            if (count($toDeleteIds) > 0) {
                $relation->detach($toDeleteIds);
            }
            if (!in_array($categoryId, $allIds)) {
                    $relation->sync($categoryId);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks. But can't I rewrite relation ```handleServices``` with ```sync``` but without ```ManyToManyHelper```?

Comment: You can use `hasMany` for a one-to-many relation. When the relation is many to many, there is (technically) no model that "owns" the other model, that's probably why `belongsToMany` is used in this case, on both models. A linguistic approach to defining table relationships can be hard to understand in some cases.